# Drawing style presentations

Tags: presentation

What tools do you use to create drawing style presentations, (something like kid's drawings)
Ofcourse we can do things like draw it on paper/some ipad application 
or do you use flash ?

for eg. 
http://www.spotify.com/int/about-us/press/concept-video/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=vbLazF5KxUc

I can see that these type of presentation can be done with camera and shooting on a white board.kind of like stop motion..

any other tips?

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately it's off topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a stack of A3 paper instead of a board for the stop motion. That way  you can start by making the story board of your story and then you can create the in between frames.